# Attempting to make series of data frames from levels of a factor column with a loop function

Tags: r

My data set consists of educational data for each state by year. I would like to make a loop that creates data frames for each state that contains all of the columns in the original data set. An example of one primary key is 1992_ALABAMA. I would like to have a data frame for Alabama that combines all years, and repeat this for every state without having to create each data frame manually.

I have tried creating a loop that takes all levels of the state factor column, and assigning the relevant rows for that specific factor with every column.

```
# this is how I did this manually for Alabama:
alabama <- data[which(data$STATE == "ALABAMA"),]


# this is the loop I am trying to use. stLevels is a character vector     
# containing all of the levels of the state factor column.
for (i in stLevels) {
  i <- data[which(data$STATE == i),]
}
```

I am hoping for 80 data frames named by their appropriate state which contains all of the observations of said state. What happens is that a data frame named "i" is created which contains all of the rows that contain Wyoming. It didn't name it correctly, and this did not happen for any of the other states.

Comment: What you want to do is just `all_states <- split(data,data$STATE)`. You don't want them in separate data frames, the named list will be much easier to work with.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like this:

```
state_dataframes = lapply(stLevels, function(x){data[data$STATE == x,]})
names(state_dataframes) = stLevels
```

This will create a list containing all the subsets you want. You can access them by calling `state_dataframes[['ALABAMA']]` If you really want to do it your way you can do this:

```
for(i in stLevels){
  assign(x = gsub(x = deparse(i), pattern = '\\"', replacement = ''), 
         value = data[which(data$STATE == i),],
         envir = globalenv())
}
```

`assign` associates a name with an object
`gsub` removes the quotes from the name
`deparse` gets the value of i in each iteration